# get ids as well for all models with seed_dump gem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Hi I am using [seed_dump](https://github.com/rroblak/seed_dump) gem to create seeds.rb from existing data but I stuck one thing I want to get ids for all models as well how can I do this for example currently if I run

```
rake db:seed:dump
```

I just get code like this

```
Product.create(title: "title", description: "text")
```

but I want this

```
Product.create(id: 1, title: "title", description: "text")
```

how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own export. Assuming that your model's name is `Country`:

**lib/tasks/export.rake**

```
namespace :export do
  desc "Exports data for using in a seeds.rb."
  task :seeds_format => :environment do
    Country.order(:id).all.each do |country|
      puts "Country.create(#{country.serializable_hash.
            delete_if {|key, value| ['created_at','updated_at'].
            include?(key)}.to_s.gsub(/[{}]/,'')})"
    end
  end
end
```

You could run that with this command:

```
rake export:seeds_format > db/seeds.rb
```

Comment: And what if I also want to save passwords I am using devise

Comment: and for paperclip also as I have images

Comment: Please create new questions for these topics.

Comment: JaTo's answer shows how to use the `seed_dump` gem rather than writing custom code.

Answer (score 13):

```
rake db:seed:dump EXCLUDE=[]
```

This overwrites the default exclude of [:id, :created_at, :updated_at] so that it includes the id

Comment: This is the official way to get the `id` field in a dump using the `seed_dump` gem.  https://github.com/rroblak/seed_dump/issues/87#issuecomment-137963502